# Can't get Bootstrap dropdown menu to work

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using the following for my bootstrap 4.0.0 link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

However, when I try to implement a basic menu, the standard links work, but if I try to click on the `Dropdown link` menu it does not seem to do anything. I am expecting it to drop down if I click on it.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">

  <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="/link 1">Link 1</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="/link 2">Link 2</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="/link 3">Link 3</a></li>

    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown link</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">link 4</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">link 5</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">link 6</a>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

What am I doing wrong and why is the menu not opening up to reveal the links 4, 5, and 6?

Comment: Did you try also including the JS/JQuery?

Comment: @JanusVarmarken No, is JS/JQuery needed here?

Comment: By far not a bootstrap expert, but it'd be the first thing I'd try just to rule it out :). Thinking about it though, I'd expect for a dropdown to "unfold", you'd need to modify the DOM. But then again, my frontend skills are very basic (not to say completely missing)

Comment: Indeed, the doc says that it requires JS as it's built on top of a third party js lib called `Popper.js`: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Comment: Please press F12 in your browser and see if there are any console messages. This is always the first stop for these kind of issues. This should be written in bold on all of these JS library download pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only included the **CSS** for Bootstrap. You need to include the **JavaScript** for Bootstrap for the dropdowns to work. You'll also need to include the references to the two dependencies, jQuery and PopperJS, **before** the reference to Bootstrap's JavaScript:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here's a working example with those added:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="/link 1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="/link 2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="/link 3">Link 3</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown link</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">link 4</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">link 5</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">link 6</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I was previously trying another drop down approach which used only CSS. I did not realize that Bootstrap required JS and even a third party library.